# Retrieving an array from Firestore DocumentSnapshot

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve an array from a Firestore document. I have an array inside each document named 'requests' that contains Strings.

The Future below never resolves when It gets called.

```
Future<List<String>> getRequests() {
  return Firestore.instance.collection('users')
      .document(uid)
      .get()
      .then((e) => e.data['requests']);
}
```

However, this code resolves to a list.

```
Future<List<String>> getRequests() {
  return Firestore.instance.collection('users')
      .document(uid)
      .get()
      .then((e) => [e.data['requests'][0]]);
}
```

Am I missing some 'toList' function?

Answer (score 0):

Your second code sample is wrapping `e.data['requests'][0]` inside a new list by surrounding it with square brackets.  Perhaps you mean to write this instead:

```
.then((e) => e.data['requests'][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the 'requests' field is an array that I want in its entirety. I used the second snippet of code to show that it was indeed an array and I could retrieve the first element of it and then turn it into a list by wrapping it in brackets.

Comment: You can try `e.data['requests'] as List`. It casts it from a JSON array to a Dart List object.

Comment: This is firestore are you sure it’s still a json string?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to be extraordinarily explicit with types and converting to string.

```
Future<List<String>> getRequests() {
  return userCollection.document(uid).get().then((e) {
    Map map = e.data;
    List<dynamic> list = map['requests'];
    // ignore: omit_local_variable_types
    List<String> newList = (list ?? []).map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
    return newList;
  });
}
```

Thank you for the suggestions